# What is the meaning of a code block after a "use module"?

Tags: perl, module

What is the significance and what is the effect of something like this (I think it is object oriented):

```
use My::Confusing::Code
{
   CITY  => { MODIFY      => 1,           
              DEFAULT     => My::Even::more::complicated->func(), 
            },
   STATE => { MODIFY      => 1,           
              DEFAULT     => 'Concatenate()', 
            },
   COUNTRY => { MODIFY       => 1,
                REQUIRED     => 0,
                DEFAULT      => 'Gabon',
               }, 
}
```

What would the My::Confusing::Code package/module/class do with the stuff in the curly braces.  Do the curly braces enclose a code block or a hash reference?

Comment: There should be a ; after the last }, at least if there is any further code in the file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a hash reference.

When you do `use Module::Foo @stuff;`, what's happening behind-the-scenes is:

```
BEGIN { 
    require "Module/Foo.pm";
    Module::Foo->import( @stuff );
};
```

Normally, the parameters passed to `import` are used to ask for symbols to be exported into your namespace. (The typical way to do this is to use the `import` subroutine from the standard [Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exporter) module.) But in this case, the module author has written a custom `import` method that takes a hashref and does stuff with it.

Comment: There are many other reasons for a module to implement an `import` method.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, the "import" function in this case uses the hash reference passed to it to initialize an entry in it's own set of symbol tables for the modules that use it.  This code implements a perl framework of sorts.